# C# VSTO Replace Images in Document before and after PrintOut

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, ms-office

i'm working on a Word VSTO Add-In to automate some Corporate Identity Stuff for the Company i work at.

I want to replace certain Images both before and after a call to `PrintOut`

This is the Method i'm currently using

```cs
public static void PrintDocumentAsPDF(this WordRibbon _, string printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF")
{

    try
    {
        // Un-Protected Document
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Unprotect("");
    }
    catch (COMException) { }

    // Replace Images in Document
    Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.DesignElement, Constants.ImageVariant.FullResolution);
    Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.Logo, Constants.ImageVariant.FullResolution);

    // Get last Active Printer
    string lastPrinter = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter;
    try
    {
        // Set temporary Active Printer
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter = printerName;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Drucker konnte nicht konfiguriert werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    try
    {
        // Print Document
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.PrintOut(
            Constants.FalseObject, // Background
            Constants.Missing, // Append
            Constants.Missing, // Range
            Constants.Missing, // Output File Name
            Constants.Missing, // From
            Constants.Missing, // To
            Constants.Missing, // Item
            Constants.Missing, // Copies
            Constants.Missing, // Pages
            Constants.Missing, // PageType
            Constants.Missing, // PrintToFile
            Constants.Missing, // Collate
            Constants.Missing, // ActivePrinterMacGX
            Constants.Missing, // ManualDuplexPrint
            Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomColumn
            Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomRow
            Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomPaperWidth
            Constants.Missing  // PrintZoomPaperHeight
        );
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Dokument konnte nicht gedruckt werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    
    // Restore Active Printer
    try
    {
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter = lastPrinter;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Ursprüngliche Druckereinstellungen konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }

    // Replace Images with low-resolution Versions
    Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.DesignElement, Constants.ImageVariant.LowResolution);
    Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.Logo, Constants.ImageVariant.LowResolution);

    try
    {
        // Protect Document
        Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Constants.FalseObject, "");
    }
    catch (COMException) { }
}
```

This is the Code for `Extensions.ReplaceImage(...)`

```cs
public static void ReplaceImage(ImageType image, ImageVariant imageVariant)
{

    try
    {
        foreach (Range storyRange in Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.StoryRanges)
        {
            foreach (Shape shape in storyRange.ShapeRange)
            {
                if (shape.AlternativeText == ImageRepository[image][imageVariant].Name)
                {
                    object anchor = shape.Anchor;
                    Shape newShape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Shapes.AddPicture(
                        ImageRepository[image][imageVariant].Path /* Image Path */,
                        // ref Constants.Missing,
                        // ref Constants.Missing,
                        // ref Constants.Missing,
                        // ref Constants.Missing,
                        // ref Constants.Missing,
                        // ref Constants.Missing,
                        Anchor: ref anchor);
                    newShape.Top = shape.Top;
                    newShape.Left = shape.Left;
                    newShape.Width = shape.Width;
                    newShape.Height = shape.Height;
                    newShape.AlternativeText = shape.AlternativeText;
                    shape.Delete();
                }
            }
            foreach (InlineShape inlineShape in storyRange.InlineShapes)
            {
                if (inlineShape.AlternativeText == ImageRepository[image][imageVariant].Name)
                {
                    InlineShape newInlineShape = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(
                        ImageRepository[image][imageVariant].Path,
                        ref Missing,
                        ref Missing,
                        inlineShape.Range
                    );
                    newInlineShape.Width = inlineShape.Width;
                    newInlineShape.Height = inlineShape.Height;
                    newInlineShape.AlternativeText = inlineShape.AlternativeText;
                    inlineShape.Delete();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (COMException comException)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(comException.Message, "COM Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
    }
}
```

Definition for Constants.FalseObject: `public static object FalseObject = false;`
Definition for Constants.Missing: `public static object Missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;`

And these are the definitions for `ImageType` and `ImageVariant`

```cs
public enum ImageType
{
    DesignElement,
    Logo
}

public enum ImageVariant
{
    LowResolution,
    FullResolution
}

public class ImageElement
{
    public string Path { get; }
    public string Name { get; }

    public ImageElement(string path, string name)
    {
        Path = path;
        Name = name;
    }
}

public static Dictionary<ImageType, Dictionary<ImageVariant, ImageElement>> ImageRepository = new Dictionary<ImageType, Dictionary<ImageVariant, ImageElement>>()
{
    [ImageType.DesignElement] = new Dictionary<ImageVariant, ImageElement>()
    {
        [ImageVariant.FullResolution] = new ImageElement(Path.Combine(LocalResourceBasePath, "Images", "DocumentTitle.png"), "Designelement"),
        [ImageVariant.LowResolution] = new ImageElement(Path.Combine(LocalResourceBasePath, "Images", "DocumentTitle_lowres.png"), "Designelement")
    },
    [ImageType.Logo] = new Dictionary<ImageVariant, ImageElement>()
    {
        [ImageVariant.FullResolution] = new ImageElement(Path.Combine(LocalResourceBasePath, "Images", "Logo_rgb.png"), "Logo"),
        [ImageVariant.LowResolution] = new ImageElement(Path.Combine(LocalResourceBasePath, "Images", "Logo_rgb_lowres.png"), "Logo")
    },
};
```

The issue is, that the second call(s) to ReplaceImage after the PrintOut()-Call are done before the First Replacement and Print is done.

I saw that there was a Event called `DocumentBeforePrint` that gets invoked before anything is being printed. Is something similar like `DocumentAfterPrint` ?

I also attempted to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11674925/word-automation-printout-wait-for-its-finished) Post to fix it, but this wouldn't work either.

Can anyone help ?
( if my code is complete garbage - which would not surprise me - i'm also open to suggestions on how to do this better )

Comment: Is this [Is there a DocumentAfterPrint event in MS Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1155970/is-there-a-documentafterprint-event-in-ms-word) helpful? And how about [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.backgroundprintingstatus?view=word-pia) [Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.application.backgroundprintingstatus)?

Comment: [how to check if word document has printed already](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510315/how-to-check-if-word-document-has-printed-already). [When using a virtual printer how can I check that print is finished?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3914880/when-using-a-virtual-printer-how-can-i-check-that-print-is-finished?rq=3)

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is, that the second call(s) to ReplaceImage after the PrintOut()-Call are done before the First Replacement and Print is done.

OK, I use [BackgroundPrintingStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word._application.backgroundprintingstatus?view=word-pia) property to wait the method PrintOut() done. It works. This is my test code:

```cs
       void Cs_VSTO_Replace_Images_in_Document_before_and_after_PrintOut()
        {
            string f = @"X:\t.docx";
            string fPrint = @"X:\t.pdf";//just for test, because I don't have a printer to test
            string pic = @"X:\2.png";


            if (File.Exists(fPrint)) File.Delete(fPrint);

            int howLongtoWaitInSeconds = 50;
            TimeSpan sp = new TimeSpan();
            DateTime t = DateTime.Now;

            int backgroundPrintingCount = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus;
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document d = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(f);
            d.PrintOut(Background: false, OutputFileName: fPrint, PrintToFile: true);
            while (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus > backgroundPrintingCount)
            {
                //Just in case.
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(t).TotalSeconds > howLongtoWaitInSeconds) break;
            }
            //if you also print to file then use Fils.Exsted to check
            /*
            while(!File.Exists(fPrint)) {
                //Just in case.
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(t).TotalSeconds > howLongtoWaitInSeconds) break;
            }
            */

            //just for test
            //d.Range().Find.Execute(FindText: "易", Replace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: "●");
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape shp in d.InlineShapes)
            {
                d.Range().InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:pic,Range:shp.Range);
                shp.Delete();
            }

            d.Close(SaveChanges: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges);
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(f);
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
            Process.Start(fPrint);
        }
```

So if in your code, it may be like:

```cs
        public static void PrintDocumentAsPDF(this WordRibbon _, string printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF")
        {

            try
            {
                // Un-Protected Document
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Unprotect("");
            }
            catch (COMException) { }

            // Replace Images in Document
            Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.DesignElement, Constants.ImageVariant.FullResolution);
            Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.Logo, Constants.ImageVariant.FullResolution);

            // Get last Active Printer
            string lastPrinter = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter;
            try
            {
                // Set temporary Active Printer
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter = printerName;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Drucker konnte nicht konfiguriert werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


            int howLongtoWaitInSeconds = 50;
            TimeSpan sp = new TimeSpan();
            DateTime t = DateTime.Now;

            int backgroundPrintingCount = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus;            
            

            try
            {
                // Print Document
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.PrintOut(
                    Constants.FalseObject, // Background
                    Constants.Missing, // Append
                    Constants.Missing, // Range
                    Constants.Missing, // Output File Name
                    Constants.Missing, // From
                    Constants.Missing, // To
                    Constants.Missing, // Item
                    Constants.Missing, // Copies
                    Constants.Missing, // Pages
                    Constants.Missing, // PageType
                    Constants.Missing, // PrintToFile
                    Constants.Missing, // Collate
                    Constants.Missing, // ActivePrinterMacGX
                    Constants.Missing, // ManualDuplexPrint
                    Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomColumn
                    Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomRow
                    Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomPaperWidth
                    Constants.Missing  // PrintZoomPaperHeight
                );
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Dokument konnte nicht gedruckt werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }

            // Restore Active Printer
            try
            {
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter = lastPrinter;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ursprüngliche Druckereinstellungen konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }


            
            while (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus > backgroundPrintingCount)
            {
                //Just in case.
                if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(t).TotalSeconds > howLongtoWaitInSeconds) break;
            }



            // Replace Images with low-resolution Versions
            Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.DesignElement, Constants.ImageVariant.LowResolution);
            Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.Logo, Constants.ImageVariant.LowResolution);

            try
            {
                // Protect Document
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Constants.FalseObject, "");
            }
            catch (COMException) { }
        }
```

- If you are still not sure then how about using the Task object Wait method to double insurance：

```cs
        void Cs_VSTO_Replace_Images_in_Document_before_and_after_PrintOut()
        {
            string f = @"X:\t.docx";
            string fPrint = @"X:\t.pdf";//just for test, because I don't have a printer to test
            string pic = @"X:\2.png";


            if (File.Exists(fPrint)) File.Delete(fPrint);

            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document d = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(f);

            System.Threading.Tasks.Task wait =
                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(() =>
                    {
                        int howLongtoWaitInSeconds = 50;
                        TimeSpan sp = new TimeSpan();
                        DateTime t = DateTime.Now;

                        int backgroundPrintingCount = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus;

                        d.PrintOut(Background: false, OutputFileName: fPrint, PrintToFile: true);
                        while (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus > backgroundPrintingCount)
                        {
                            //Just in case.
                            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(t).TotalSeconds > howLongtoWaitInSeconds) break;
                        }
                        //if you also print to file then use Fils.Exsted to check
                        /*
                        while(!File.Exists(fPrint)) {
                            //Just in case.
                            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(t).TotalSeconds > howLongtoWaitInSeconds) break;
                        }
                        */
                    }
                    );

            wait.Wait();

            //just for test
            //d.Range().Find.Execute(FindText: "易", Replace: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdReplace.wdReplaceAll, ReplaceWith: "●");
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Exclamation.Play();
            foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.InlineShape shp in d.InlineShapes)
            {
                d.Range().InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName: pic, Range: shp.Range);
                shp.Delete();
            }

            d.Close(SaveChanges: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdSaveChanges);
            Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Documents.Open(f);
            System.Media.SystemSounds.Asterisk.Play();
            Process.Start(fPrint);
        }
```

And you code will be:

```cs
        public static void PrintDocumentAsPDF(this WordRibbon _, string printerName = "Microsoft Print to PDF")
        {

            System.Threading.Tasks.Task wait = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run(()=>{

                try
                {
                    // Un-Protected Document
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Unprotect("");
                }
                catch (COMException) { }

                // Replace Images in Document
                Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.DesignElement, Constants.ImageVariant.FullResolution);
                Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.Logo, Constants.ImageVariant.FullResolution);

                // Get last Active Printer
                string lastPrinter = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter;
                try
                {
                    // Set temporary Active Printer
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter = printerName;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Drucker konnte nicht konfiguriert werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }


                int howLongtoWaitInSeconds = 50;
                TimeSpan sp = new TimeSpan();
                DateTime t = DateTime.Now;

                int backgroundPrintingCount = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus;


                try
                {
                    // Print Document
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.PrintOut(
                        Constants.FalseObject, // Background
                        Constants.Missing, // Append
                        Constants.Missing, // Range
                        Constants.Missing, // Output File Name
                        Constants.Missing, // From
                        Constants.Missing, // To
                        Constants.Missing, // Item
                        Constants.Missing, // Copies
                        Constants.Missing, // Pages
                        Constants.Missing, // PageType
                        Constants.Missing, // PrintToFile
                        Constants.Missing, // Collate
                        Constants.Missing, // ActivePrinterMacGX
                        Constants.Missing, // ManualDuplexPrint
                        Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomColumn
                        Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomRow
                        Constants.Missing, // PrintZoomPaperWidth
                        Constants.Missing  // PrintZoomPaperHeight
                    );
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Dokument konnte nicht gedruckt werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }

                // Restore Active Printer
                try
                {
                    Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePrinter = lastPrinter;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Ursprüngliche Druckereinstellungen konnte nicht wiederhergestellt werden!", "Fehler", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }



                while (Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.BackgroundPrintingStatus > backgroundPrintingCount)
                {
                    //Just in case.
                    if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(t).TotalSeconds > howLongtoWaitInSeconds) break;
                }

            });

            wait.Wait();

            // Replace Images with low-resolution Versions
            Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.DesignElement, Constants.ImageVariant.LowResolution);
            Extensions.ReplaceImage(Constants.ImageType.Logo, Constants.ImageVariant.LowResolution);

            try
            {
                // Protect Document
                Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.Protect(WdProtectionType.wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Constants.FalseObject, "");
            }
            catch (COMException) { }
        }
```

Would you like to take a chance?

However, your function is named `PrintDocumentAsPDF`, but the arguments `PrintToFile` and `OutputFileName` both are `Constants.Missing` in your code. How can yours print to file as PDF without going along like mine?